# Save data exactly, at opening csv file in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have csv file which contains data   `0001,0002,0003`

When I open this file in excel, starting nulls are removed

Its possible to save starting nulls at opening file in excel ?

Comment: Are you asking about nulls as in " " (a space) or as in leading zeros?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To do this, open Excel first.

Click on `Data` > `Import from text`.

You will get a window where you'll have to pick the import type. Choose `Delimited` then next.

In the next screen, check only `comma`, then next.

On this screen, click the first column in the preview box, scroll to the last column. Hold SHIFT and click the last column. This should make all the columns 'black' (you actually selected all the columns).

Now, click the radio button `Text`. After that, click Finish and OK to get your data as you wanted it to be!

Answer (score 1):

If you are able to control the generation of your CSV file, you can force Excel to interpret the input as text by saving it as follows:

```
="0001",="0002",="0003"
```

(Be careful that you use typewriter quotes, as above, rather than curly [smart] quotes.)